# DirectAccess Multisite and Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, iis, wget, vpn, azure-traffic-manager

I have a DirectAccess Multisite deployment configured with two entry points around the world. I want to use Azure Traffic Manager as a GSLB solution as described here: https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2016/04/04/directaccess-multisite-geographic-redundancy-with-microsoft-azure-traffic-manager/

I can add one of my entry points as an endpoint in Traffic Manager but my other entry point won't change status from Degraded in Azure.

I have troubleshooted the entry point with wget:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin> .\wget.exe https://<DA_URL>/IPHTTPS --no-check-certificate
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2018-08-30 19:48:57--  https://<DA_URL>/IPHTTPS
Resolving <DA_URL>... xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
Connecting to <DA_URL>|xxx.xxx.xxx.xx|:443... connected.
HTTP request send, awaiting respons... Read error (Result too large) in headers.
```

What could be wrong with my DA server? IIS issue?

My other entry point from the same Direct Access Multisite deployment are responding with HTTP 200 - OK.

This is resolved! Follow this simple steps to set things up! https://thoor.tech/2018/09/direct-access-and-azure-traffic-manager/

Comment: Capture the bytes you sent and see if it goes beyond the limit `MaxFieldLength` https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows

Comment: Hi Lex! I don't know how to do that, could you give me some guidance?

Comment: This is now solved. Needed to change monitoring to TCP from HTTPS in Azure Traffic Manager. https://thoor.tech/2018/09/direct-access-and-azure-traffic-manager/

Comment: @pthoor  You can put the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. Needed to change monitoring to TCP from HTTPS in Azure Traffic Manager. [thoor.tech/2018/09/direct-access-and-azure-traffic-manager](http://thoor.tech/2018/09/direct-access-and-azure-traffic-manager)